# Include external PHP application into iFrame (Twig/Symfony)

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony4

I am working on a proof-of-concept project that needs to be built quickly, so we are taking shortcuts. I have created the basic Symfony/Twig structure. A colleague has created a PHP application that we want to include into an iFrame on the site (eventually we will do this by means of proper templates, etc.).

I created the following **index.html.twig** (simplified):

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <iframe src="project/index.php"></iframe>
{% endblock %}
```

This throws me an error:

> Unable to find template "project/index.php"

I understand the error, but am not sure what to do so that the external application simply gets loaded into the iFrame. Basically I want Symfony and Twig to ignore it (for now, so it can be used as prove of concept).

Comment: the path for that uri should not be interpreted at all, whatever you "simplified" probably makes lots of difference. but overall, it could just be a misconfigured webserver. can you call the uri "manually" outside the iframe?

Comment: With 'simplified' I merely mean that I didn't include all details of the template in the example (stylesheets, content data, etc.). If I remove the iframe line (did so by comment tags), all is well as far as the parser/webserver goes (meaning no 'LoaderError').

Comment: Oh, and calling it separately works. Sorry. Forgot to mention that. Thank you, @Jakumi for answering.

Comment: Make sure the URL is correct and your mod_rewrite allows you to visit (physical) existing files

Comment: Both of you helped. It turns out that this is a server configuration error. Thank you for your helpful comments.

Comment: Two people streamlined my post to an (incomplete ;-) degree days after it has been answered. Guess there lies some enjoyment therein. :-) Is there any benefit in this for the zealous editor? Am new to SO. Just wondering... some might find mere grammar corrections offensive, but if there's a benefit I'd love to know.

Answer (score 0):

I will make an assumption here, specifically, that your code is included in a template for `/app/somethingelse` (two slashes or more).

which will lead to, the uri in the following (your code)

```
<iframe src="project/index.php"></iframe>
```

to be interpreted as `/app/project/index.php` - since it's a relative path -, which most likely doesn't exist. What you probably want is an absolute path (which always begins with a slash):

```
{% block body %}
    <iframe src="/project/index.php"></iframe>
{% endblock %}{# ^here #}
```

I suggest reading up on relative vs. absolute paths. combined with the comment, that you almost always want absolute paths (unless full URLs are necessary of course) - this also includes paths to images, paths to css files, paths to anything and everything really. relative paths can be quite handy, but you always have to be aware that the relative position of locations gets relevant and cannot be changed without impacting other places where those relative positions are assumed to be static.