# Drupal 8/9 how do I allow specific sub-folder to execute python scripts?

Tags: python, drupal-8

I have a Drupal 9.x site running in the web-root directory (public_html/). I need to run some python scripts (currently in public_html/python/) and show the output in an iframe called in a Drupal twig template. Permissions on the python files are 755 but when I load the page that calls the iframe, it shows the python code instead of executing the script and showing the output.

How can I exempt a specific custom subfolder in the drupal file tree to allow (python) file execution?

If I run Drupal in a subfolder (public_html/drupal9/..) and I reference the python scripts below the drupal webroot folder (public_html/python/script.py) it all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

you should use php exec
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

I recommend to you, to put the python scripts in another directory

For example create a directory called /home/pythonScripts

```
$ mkdir /home/pythonScripts
$ touch /home/pythonScripts/hola.py
$ echo "print (\"Python\")" > hola.py
$ chmod +x /home/pythonScripts/hola.py
```

(of course, you will use your own python script)

Verify where is python with:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

And of course, you can run this programm with:

```
$ python /home/pythonScripts/hola.py
Python
```

or (it is the same)

```
$ /usr/bin/python /home/pythonScripts/hola.py
Python
```

In your module, PHP code!!

```
<?php
....
$binPython="/usr/bin/python";
$pathPythonScripts="/home/pythonScripts/";
// name of the script
$script="hola.py";

$result = exec($binPython." ".$pathPythonScripts.$script);
```

Of course, you can add validations, etc.

And then you can use $result to be used in twig template

Regards

Leonardo

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful reply. It will help many people. While it's a valuable work-around, it doesn't answer the question. I use php exec in other cases but for this use-case it's not an alternative. I have a functioning python script that is used on it's own via a browser (it takes $var[xxx] variables as _GET parameters from a Twig file) and I don't want to support multiple instances of the same script. I was able to find a partial solution using this VERY OLD post https://www.drupal.org/node/30334 and then ensuring I had a properly configured .htaccess in the /python/ direcorty.

Comment: Hi Dean, excuse my misunderstanding.

Comment: I think the way could be or using an ajax call or another way  something  like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57795803/include-external-php-application-into-iframe-twig-symfony (in this case the external app will be python), and this python script is correctly configured in the http server to attend requests .